# Moving manually multiple labels of one field

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have multiple labels of one field which in some scenarios I'd like to move manually to avoid overlapping etc.

But the problem is if I have multiple labels and choose **Data defined placement** in labels options (x,y coordinates) and move my label it's merged to one label instead of displaying multiple.

I know it's related to coordinates, I can choose only 1 field for **Coordinate X** and 1 field for **Coordinate Y**...

[image: example]

Do you know how to be able to move multiple labels of one field?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the EasyCustomLabeling extension.

At first, the extension will ask you for a labelling field and then create a new layer.

By opening the attribute table of this new layer, you can see the x and y position of each label and modify them directly in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

an other possibility will be to use rule-based labels, there you can define datadefined override for each rule. you will need different placement fields for that: you can use the auxilary storage where you can define multiple fields for that purpose, see screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]